# Finding all integers $x$, $y$, $z$ satisfying $3x^2=y(y+2)=z^3-1$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

> Find all integers $x,y,z$ such that
> $$3x^2=y(y+2)=z^3-1$$

This is one exercise in trial test of my local. First, I see that from $y(y+2)=z^3-1$, one obtains $(y+1)^2=z^3$. Therefore, $(y+1)^2=b^3$ and $z=c^2$.

This result is a direct consequence of the result which was prove by J. H. E. Cohn in https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/42.1.27. But i wonder if we have any simplier way to approach?
Thanks

Comment: Did you mean $(y+1)=b^3$? Also you have only solved $y(y+2)=z^3-1$, but that does not mean it will solve $3x^2=\cdots $ part (for example $c=2$ gives you $z=4$, but $z^3-1=63=3x^2$ has no solution in integers)

Comment: i had some mistake! sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've made the observation that you made, you get $3x^2=s^6-1$ for some positive integer $s$. Factor this as
$$3x^2=(s^3-1)(s^3+1).$$
Now, the greatest common factor of the two factors on the right side is either $1$ or $2$. If it is $1$, one of the factors must be a square and the other must be $3$ times a square, and if it is $2$ then they must be $2$ and $6$ times squares (they can't be $1$ and $3$ times squares since one would be $\equiv 2\bmod 4$). This is a consequence of the property that, if a perfect square is factored into relatively prime factors, they are each squares.

To solve the first case, we examine the factor that is a pure square;
$$s^3\pm 1 = t^2.$$
This can be factored as $(s\pm 1)(s^2\mp s+1)=t^2$. The greatest common factor of these factors is either $1$ or $3$, but it can't be $3$, since $(s^3\pm 1)\mp 2$ is a multiple of $3$. Thus, $s^2\mp s+1$ is a square. However, this is strictly between $(s\mp 1)^2$ and $s^2$ for $s>1$, and for $s=1$ we have only the trivial $t=0\implies x=0$.

In the second case, we have
$$(s\pm 1)(s^2\mp s+1)=s^3\pm 1=2t^2.$$
Again, these two factors are relatively prime, so one is a square and one is twice a square. The square cannot be the second factor for the same reason as before, but that factor cannot be twice a square as it is odd. This concludes the proof.

Comment: I think the case one of $s^3+1,s^3-1$ is square and  the other is 3 times square can be occurr. If $s^3+1=a^2,s^3-1=3b^2$, it doesn't obtain some contradiction!

Comment: @DatTran I think it should; once $(s+1)(s^2-s+1)=a^2$ and $3\nmid a^2$, we must have that $s+1$ and $s^2-s+1$ are both squares, since $$\gcd(s+1,s^2-s+1)=\gcd(s+1,3)=1.$$ However, $s^2-s+1$ can't be a square, since it's between $(s-1)^2$ and $s^2$ (unless $s=0$ or $s=1$, which are simple to deal with).